# filter function isn't return right value

Tags: javascript

My filter function in javascript isn't working:

```
var a=["apple", ""];
a.filter(function(x){x.length<0});
a// expect to return ["apple"], but get []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter function needs to return a value. I'm also guessing you want `.length > 0` since there is no such thing as a string with a *negative* length. Finally, the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method will return a new array, so you'll probably want to capture the result in `a`.

In the end, it would look something like this:

```
a = a.filter(function(x){return x.length > 0});
```